# How to keep track of different push device tokens and when they change

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We have a service where we now want to push out information about points of interest to our users.

The thing is that we want the user to be able to configure interest in point A, B and F on device 1 and point C and G on device 2. This configuration would of course be stored on the server, linked to the user accounts they use when logging in, so we know to which device to push what message to the user.

But according to the doc, the "device token" can change at any time, even if it's the same install. One way would be to store the token locally too, so that i know when it changes and can send "old" and "new" to the server and update the right config for the right app ID.

But that would not solve the case where the user uninstalls and reinstalls. Also, Apple writes in its Remote notifications guide:

```
"Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your provider; 
always get the token from the system whenever you need it."
```

So, how would i then solve this issue? Is it solvable?

Thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never any way to identify an old install after a reinstall unless you have some kind of login. All identifiers get reset after an install, meaning that there is nothing linking the old instance of the app to the new one. If you have a login you can tie the notifications to that account and whenever someone logs in, add that device's token to the list of devices to be notified about that user's points.

When it comes to identifying a change in tokens for an installed device, your idea of saving the token is the one I've done. On each launch I usually check the token against a copy I've saved and if it's different I send it to the server.

In order to remove orphaned tokens you can use Apple's feedback service which gives you info about expired tokens and user's who have switched notifications off. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) for more info.

Comment: Hey thanks for quick response! :) Of course they have logins, edited the question to clarify. OK, so you also did the token caching, cool. As you say, that solves one thing, but not the other. What would happen would be that i get an "orphan" device token with config on every user app reinstall, and the user would have to re-create the config for that device. But if there's nothing to do about it, i guess i'll have to live with it.

Comment: Apple has a feedback service which I think deals with just that. I haven't done much of the back-end programming, so I'm not entirely familiar with it but that's what I gather from the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3

Comment: Thanks mate, i've actually already read up on the feedback stuff. I'll end up sending unnecessary stuff, but at least i'll know when the device tokens are not around anymore so that i can remove them.

Comment: Yup, Apple's recommendation is to check it once per day, so depending on the amount of notifications being sent you can end up sending quite a bit of unnecessary data.

Comment: If this answered your question feel free to mark it as the answer and upvote it :)